# undefined function in timeout angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller :

```
app.controller('ListeSASController', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, userService, RefreshSASServices, $timeout){
        this.IsUserLogged = function()
        {
            return userService.user().isLogged;
        };

        var promise = $timeout(RefreshSASServices.RafraichirSAS(), 100);

        this.getSAS = function(){
            return RefreshSASServices.getSAS();
        };

        $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
            RefreshSASServices.ArreterLesRafraichissements();
        });
});
```

with the following service :

```
app.service('RefreshSASServices', function($http, userService, serverConfigService, $q, $timeout, $translate, constantsServices) {
    var listeSAS = [];
    var $this = this;

    var promiseRefreshSAS;

    // Getters
    this.getSAS = function()
    {
        return listeSAS;
    };


    //Setters
    this.clearDatas = function()
    {
        listeSAS = [];
    };


    // Communication with the server
    $this.getServerUri = function()
    {
        return serverConfigService.getServerUri()+"majsvc/";
    };




    // Fonctions de rafraichissement
    $this.ArreterLesRafraichissements = function()
    {
        if(promiseRefreshSAS !== undefined)
            $timeout.cancel(promiseRefreshSAS);
    };

    $this.GetSASFromServer = function()
    {
        var promises;
        if(userService.user().isLogged)
        {
            var uri = $this.getServerUri() + "getAllSAS/"+userService.user().UserObject._id;
            promises = $http.get(uri)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                return data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                return "";
            });
        }else{
            promises = $q.when(!userService.user().isLogged)
        }
        return promises;    
    };
    $this.RafraichirSAS = function () {
    // functions that call
            $this.GetSASFromServer()
            .then(function(promise){

                if(promise !== undefined && promise.data !== undefined)
                {
                    listeSAS = promise.data;
                    //alert('refreshing the SAS list:' + JSON.stringify(listeSAS));

                }else listeSAS = [];
                promiseRefreshSAS = $timeout($this.RafraichirSAS, 3000);
            })
            .catch(function(error)
            {
                console.error("Error :", error);
                promiseRefreshSAS = $timeout($this.RafraichirSAS, 7000);
            });
    };





});
```

When I load my page using routes :

```
.when('/listeSAS', {
                templateUrl : './includes/sas/liste_sas.html',
                controller  : 'ListeSASController',
                controllerAs : 'controller'
            })
```

everything works fine, if my data changes on the server it gets updated on the UI, My UI is also displaying what I want. Everything is OK except that when the pages loads I get the following error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at file:///includes/libs/angular.js:14305:28
    at completeOutstandingRequest (file:///includes/libs/angular.js:4397:10)
    at file:////includes/libs/angular.js:4705:7
```

which is the function "timeout" of angular, and the line 14305 is :

```
try {
          deferred.resolve(fn());
        } catch(e) {
          deferred.reject(e);
          $exceptionHandler(e);
        }
        finally {
          delete deferreds[promise.$$timeoutId];
        }
```

Why angular is throwing this exception ? What did I do wrong ?
To be known :
On my login page I set 2 timeouts which I don't stop because they refresh "global" variables such as the number of private messages. Despite the error both timeout are still working.

I use node webkit with my application and it crashes maybe one in three times when I open this route (after 5-10 seconds).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you're calling RafraichirSAS(), which returns undefined instead of passing in the function?

E.g, instead of

```
$timeout(RefreshSASServices.RafraichirSAS(), 100);
```

Do

```
$timeout(RefreshSASServices.RafraichirSAS, 100);
```